# Is there a way to tell listings what to do immediately after escaping?

Tags: listings

What I want to do is having two or more possibilities when escaping from normal code formatting. For instance, if I give the option `escapechar=\⠶` I would like to avoid saying something like this:

```
\begin{lstlistings}[language=C,escapechar=\⠶]
double a;
int i; ⠶\color{red}$\longleftarrow$ this is counter $i$⠶
\end{lstlistings}
```

I just want to escape with the given (unusual) character `⠶` being sure that the color command is automatically given. In other words, the escaped text in the following code:

```
\begin{lstlistings}[language=C,escapechar=\⠶]
double a;
int i; ⠶$\longleftarrow$ this is counter $i$⠶
\end{lstlistings}
```

should be in red.

Similarly, instead of this:

```
\begin{lstlistings}[language=C,escapechar=\£]
double a; £\color{green}$\longleftarrow$ this is the variable $a$£
int i;
\end{lstlistings}
```

I want to escape with the character `£` being sure that a green text is typeset.

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer, so that your question be removed from the "unanswered" pile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given by the options `escapebegin` and `escapeend`:

```
\begin{lstlistings}[language=C,escapechar=\⠶,escapebegin=\color{red},escapeend={}]
double a;
int i; ⠶$\longleftarrow$ this is counter $i$⠶
\end{lstlistings}
```

give a red comment.